# Complete characterization of equiangular polygons with two alternating edge lengths

Tags: symmetry, angle, polygons

I am looking for a complete characterization of equiangular polygons with two alternating edge lengths.
Also self-intersections are allowed (as seen here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogonal_figure ; figure D3 and D7).

Does anyone know literature dealing with these classes of polygons?

Comment: Semiregular Polygons by Oleg Mushkarov and Nikolai Nikolov, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 113, No. 4 (Apr., 2006), pp. 339-344 might be of interest.

Comment: The topic also comes up in Section 5 of http://www.iejgeo.com/matder/dosyalar/makale-29/colakoglu-11-2-2-09.pdf